# How to adjust the alignment of cventry?

Tags: positioning, alignment, moderncv, cv

I'm trying to align the cventries so that there could be some space on the left and right, just like what *adjustwidth* does.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{moderncv}     
\moderncvstyle{banking}   
\usepackage[margin=1cm, bottom=1.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{changepage}


\newcommand{\mycventry}[6]{\cventry{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}{#5}{#6}}

\name{John}{Doe}

\begin{document}
\maketitle


\section{Objective Summary}

\begin{adjustwidth}{0.3cm}{0.3cm}
\small Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus rutrum scelerisque turpis, nec ullamcorper lacus ullamcorper vel. Integer pellentesque ante vitae quam condimentum pretium. Morbi sed turpis convallis, convallis turpis sit amet, porttitor odio. 
\end{adjustwidth}


\section{EDUCATION}

\begin{adjustwidth}{0.3cm}{0.3cm}
\mycventry{Jan. 2020 – May 2023}{XXX University}{Bachelor of Science in XXX}{US}{}{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus rutrum scelerisque turpis, nec ullamcorper lacus ullamcorper vel. }
\end{adjustwidth}

\end{document}
```

[image]
*adjustwidth* works well for plain text but there is misalignment for cventry on the right side.
Is there a straightforward way to achieve such effect for cventry?

Comment: Off-topic: Please not, that `\small` is a font switch not a command with argument. So `\small{…}` does not make sense, but `{\small …\par}` or sometimes (maybe your case) just removing the `{` and `}`.

Comment: Welcome. // If you try to compile your code snippet in a fresh file, you'll understand what problems we have with it. To upgrade I suggest to follow this checklist and substitute with an improved version of your code: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that/10137#10137 . Thank you

Comment: Thank you for reminding. Just updated the wording and added more details

Comment: Fine. // Looks like moderncv ignores whatever you change once you call `\cventry`. My suggestions: a) add showframe to the options of geometry to see the various margins, b) if not yet done: read the manual https://mirror.clientvps.com/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/moderncv/manual/moderncv_userguide.pdf , c) try living with the standard first before you start fine-tuning: often using shorter phrases or words have better results than layout tuning.